# Which processes are accessing CD/DVD drive?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, sysinternals, thrashing

I'm trying to install StarCraft 1 on my Windows 7 machine, but it's taking forever and it sounds like the DVD drive is thrashing. Is there any way to see which processes are reading from the DVD drive? It doesn't look like Resource Monitor provides any DVD info that I can find. I'm looking at the SysInternals Suite but I'm not sure which, if any, tool is relevant...

Answer (score 0):

Using Process Monitor, I was able to pinpoint a svchost.exe process running with a commandline argument of 'secsvcs' and accessing the DVD drive. El Internet told me that was Windows Defender, and Process Explorer's Services tab on the same PID confirmed. Tried to turn off the options in Windows Defender, and it persisted. Couldn't kill it in ProcExplorer. I tried to stop the service in the Administrative Tools, but that didn't work. Finally, just killing the process caused the thrashing to stop almost immediately.